# Configurar horário específico no AlarmManager pelo TimePicker e DatePicker

Tags: android, calendar, android-alarmmanager

estou fazendo um teste ainda antes de implementar no aplicativo real. Tenho um aplicação com dois botões (Data e Horário) e um botão (Agendar). Assim que usuário clica no botão Data, abre um DatePicker para ele escolher a data. No horário é a mesma coisa, abre um TimePicker para que ele escolha o horário. A data e hora vão para um EditText para o usuário possa visualizar e assim poder tocar no botão Agendar.

Não estou conseguindo colocar o Horário no AlarmManager. Se eu configurar apenas a data funciona, mas se eu configurar a data e horário, a notificação já exibida logo em seguida.

Códido Main

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText dataEscolhida;
    private EditText materia;
    private EditText horarioEscolhido;
    private Button calendarioData;
    private Button horarioAgendado;

    private Button botaoAgendar;

    SimpleDateFormat formatarData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat formatarHora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dataEscolhida = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_dataEscolhida);
        materia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_materia);
        botaoAgendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_agendarNotificacao);
        calendarioData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_calendárioDatePicker);
        horarioAgendado = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_horario);
        horarioEscolhido = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_horario);


        botaoAgendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String dataAgendada = dataEscolhida.getText().toString();
                Log.d("Data agendada", String.valueOf(dataAgendada));

                String materiaAgendada = materia.getText().toString();
                agendarNotificacao(getNotification(materiaAgendada), calendar.getTime());

                Log.d("Agendamento", "Agendou");

            }
        });

        calendarioData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                atualizarData();
            }
        });

        horarioAgendado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                atualizaHorario();
            }
        });

    }

    private void exibeDataNoCampo() {
        dataEscolhida.setText(formatarData.format(calendar.getTime()));
        Log.d("Data escolhida: ", String.valueOf(dataEscolhida));
    }

    private void exibeHorarioNoCampo() {

        horarioEscolhido.setText(formatarHora.format(calendar.getTime()));

        Log.d("Hora escolhida: ", String.valueOf(horarioEscolhido));
    }

    private void atualizarData() {

        new DatePickerDialog(this, data, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }

//Salva a data que o usuário configurou
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener data = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            exibeDataNoCampo();
        }
    };

    private void atualizaHorario() {
        new TimePickerDialog(this, horario, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
    }

//Salva o horário que o usuário configurou
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener horario = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            exibeHorarioNoCampo();

        }
    };

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void agendarNotificacao(Notification notification, Date dataAgendada) {

        Intent intentNotificacao = new Intent(this, Notificacao.class);
        calendar.setTime(dataAgendada);

        //Irá gerar as id aleatorias para cada notificação
        int id = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);

        intentNotificacao.putExtra(Notificacao.NOTIFICATION_ID, id);
        intentNotificacao.putExtra(Notificacao.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intentNotificacao,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // long tempodedisparo =  calendar.getTimeInMillis() + segundosAgendado * 60000 ;

        //disparo de notificacao
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);

        Log.d("AgendarNOtificacao", "agendarnotificacao");
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private Notification getNotification(String content) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Lembrete: Estudar a matéria");
        builder.setContentText(content);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        Log.d("Construindo Notificacao", "Construindo Notificacao");

        return builder.build();

    }

}
```

Minha classe de Broadcast

```
public class Notificacao extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

        //som da mensagem
        try {
            Uri som = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone toque = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, som);
            toque.play();

        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }

        Log.d("Notificação Exibida", "Notificacao Exibida");
    }
}
```

Meu XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="notificacaocomalarmmanager.com.flaviodeoliveira.notificacaocomalarmmanager.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edt_materia"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:hint="Qual materia?"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edt_dataEscolhida"
        android:hint="Data?"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt_materia"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Agendar Notificação"
        android:id="@+id/btn_agendarNotificacao"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_horario"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calendario"
        android:id="@+id/btn_calendárioDatePicker"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edt_horario"

        android:hint="Horário"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt_dataEscolhida"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Horário"
        android:id="@+id/btn_horario"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_calendárioDatePicker"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> [...]a notificação já exibida logo em seguida...

Isso porque realmente você está definindo para que seja exibida logo em seguida. A clicar em `botaoAgendar`, você está passando a hora atual, usando `calendar.getTime()`, para definição do alarme, quando na verdade deveria ser o horário definido no `EditText`.

Para corrigir, basta passar como parâmetro o horário correto definido no `TimePicker` e `DatePicker`, no qual deseja que apareça a notificação no método `agendarNotificacao()`;

Comment: dentro do método botaoAgendar, troquei o `String dataAgendada = dataEscolhida.getText().toString();`   >>> Aqui eu estou pegando a data 

para `Date dataAgendada = (Date) dataEscolha.getText();`  

`agendarNotificacao(getNotification(materiaAgendada), dataAgendada);`  

Mas surge o erro no Logcat 

` java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder cannot be cast to java.util.Date `

O `dataAgenda` estou passando também no `private void agendarNotificacao(Notification notification, Date dataAgendada) `

Comment: Você tem que converter sua string para formato Date.